# gnome-terminal default font for not supported characters

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, fonts, unicode, ubuntu-font-family

How to check what is the default font used by gnome-terminal, when user defined font doesn't support some characters?

I have configured monospace-font as 'Ubuntu Mono'.

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name
'Ubuntu Mono 12'
```

When I check this font by `fc-query` it appears that, there is no support for Unicode Braille characters (range starting from 0x2800) - row `0028` is missing

```
$ fc-query /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/UbuntuMono-R.ttf
...
charset: 
0000: 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff 7fffffff 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
0001: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
0002: ffffffff ffffffff 0000ffff 00000000 00040000 10000000 3f0002c0 00000000
0003: 00020000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ffffd770 fffffffb 00007fff 00000000
0004: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 003c000c fffffc00 ffffffff ffffffff 03ffffff
001e: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000003f 00000000 00000000 000c0000
001f: 3f3fffff ffffffff aaff3f3f 3fffffff ffffffff ffdfffff efcfffdf 7fdcffff
0020: 77380000 06010047 00000010 03f10000 000003ff 02105000 00000000 00000000
0021: 00480000 00004044 7ff80000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0022: 46268044 00000800 00000100 00000031 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0025: 11111005 10101010 ffff0000 00001fff 000e0100 00000000 00000400 00000000
00e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 80000000
```

But I'm still able to print such characters in console, so my guess is that gnome-terminal use some other (not configured by user) fonts. How to check what font it is?
[image]

Comment: I guess the mapping from "Ubuntu Mono 12" to ".../UbuntuMono-R.ttf" is incomplete, probably you should dig into fontconfig's configuration. The story is not specific to gnome-terminal, the Braille dots also appear with `pango-view --font 'Ubuntu Mono 12' --text $'\u287F'`. gnome-terminal doesn't have any built-in  fallback. Hope I could help to some extent, I'm not familiar with fontconfig, pango etc. to provide more help.